# Cocoa forControlEvents:WHATGOESHERE

Tags: cocoa, nsbutton

In Cocoa/Objective-C if I have created a button programmatically, what do I put in for my control event?

```
[btnMakeChar addTarget:self action:@selector(makeChar:) forControlEvents:WHAT GOES HERE?];
```

In iOS you can write it like so forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside

I can't find anything to show what I would use for just cocoa, not cocoa touch

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but if you're programming a Mac,

```
[theHappyButton setTarget:self];
[theHappyButton setAction:@selector(doStuff)];
```

it is two separate lines, rather than the one combined line of code on an iPhone.

I hope that is what you were after??

To find it in the doco: choose on the 10.6 doco (not iOS) and search on "setAction:". You'll see it in NSControl Class Reference. NSButton is of course a subclass of NSControl.

Answer (score 2):

The method you're asking about does not exist in Cocoa, so nothing goes there. Cocoa controls have a single target with a single action, and either use a different `addTarget:`-type method for each kind of action or expect a delegate object that will handle all the events they generate.