# Set Button selector (on click event) at runtime ? (Cocoa : Mac Project)

Tags: xcode, cocoa, xcode4, xcode4.4

Any idea how to set button selector at runtime (on click event) for mac (Not IOS)

I have a view controller with a button declared as outlet :

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface MyView : NSView
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSButton *MyBtn;
```

i can access that buton with something like this :

```
MyView * v;
.
.
.
[v MyBtn]
```

i didn't find "addTarget" choice like on cocoa touch.
The only choice is "setTarget(id)"

I'm using Xcode 4.4.1 for osx mountain lion

any suggestion would be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shall look at the [**NSControl** class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSControl) (from which **NSButton** inherits) for two separate methods `setTarget:` and `setAction:`.

You can do something like this in your code:

```
[MyBtn setTarget:self];
[MyBtn setAction:@selector(doStuff)];
```

take a look also at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685886/cocoa-forcontroleventswhatgoeshere).

Answer (score 1):

those two methods are what you are looking for.

- (void)setTarget:(id)target;
- (void)setSelector:(SEL)selector;

================

```
[myButton setSelector:@selector(myButtonClickEvent:)];


-(void) myButtonClickEvent:(id) sender{
       NSLog(@"button:%@ be clicked. :)", sender);
}
```