# Objective-C, changing NSButton functionality?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsbutton

How can I change the functionality of a button that I used previously? For example, If I had a button that did "Proceed/Cancel" and let's say you "Proceed" the button would change to something such as "View/Go Back"? Basically I want to re-use the same button for something else, but since I don't know how maybe someone can help me understand it better. Thank you.

```
- (IBAction)someButton:(NSButton *)sender {

       if ([someString isEqualToString:someThing]) {
            isAllowed = YES;
            [oneButton setTitle:@"Proceed"];
            [self continue];
        }
        else {
            [oneButton setTitle:@"Cancel"];
            return;
            }
        }

- (void)continue {

// I would like to make someButton (above) take on different functionality 
// here if that's even possible. such as:

  [oneButton setTitle:@"View"];
  [self whatNow];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At some point in your program lifecycle you could replace the previous target and/or action of a `NSButton` by the desired one.

```
[oneButton setAction:@selector(continue)];
```

This will cause your `continue` selector to be called instead of the `someButton:` for the `oneButton` instance.

OBS: just pay attention at your selectors as the one from the NIB file has a parameter `@selector(someButton:)` and the one you are creating does not have any, so it stays as `@selector(continue)`

as seen here: [Cocoa forControlEvents:WHATGOESHERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685886/cocoa-forcontroleventswhatgoeshere)

Comment: thank you - i'll give this a try. One more question I have; is it possible to have a button target two methods at the same time?

Comment: @JoeHabadas yes, sure! you can have many targets/action pairs for the same UIControlEvent, just keep in mind that they will be fired up in the same order they were added

Comment: also, it is possible to remove al targets/actions at once: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340825/uibutton-remove-all-target-actions - I will add an edit for this :)

Comment: Thanks very much Felipe. I'm trying to use this with Cocoa; do you know the Mac equivalent to UIControlEventAllEvents, etc?

Comment: @JoeHabadas hmm sorry, I completely ignored the `nsbutton` at the question and went for the uibutton methods

Comment: just updated my answer and as far as I know, you won't be able and you don't need to do it as NSButton has only one target/action, and not a collection